# Nginx and drupal

Tags: drupal, nginx, drupal-6

I run drupal 6 using nginx but when I run mydomain.com/update.php it does not seem to complete properly. I've tweaked the config to run it but I see no results after clicking the "update" button. it never leaves the update page. This leads me to believe that the update has not happened

My question

- how to get update.php to complete properly.

In the nginx framework I used to set it up to run drupal there is a file included which sets up access to update.php it is below: notice that I have removed any .htaccess related security for the time being so I can get update and/or cron to run.

```
# -*- mode: nginx; mode:autopair; mode: flyspell-prog; ispell-local-dictionary: "american" -*-
### Configuration file for Drupal if you're not using drush to update your site or run cron.

## XMLRPC. Comment out if not enabled.
location = /xmlrpc.php {
    fastcgi_pass phpcgi;
    # To use Apache for serving PHP uncomment the line bellow and
    # comment out the above.
    #proxy_pass http://phpapache;
}

## Restrict cron access to a specific host.
location = /cron.php {
#    ## If not allowed to run cron then issue a 404 and redirect to the
#    ## site root.
#    if ($not_allowed_cron) {
#        return 404 /;
#    }
    fastcgi_pass phpcgi;
#    ## To use Apache for serving PHP uncomment the line bellow and
#    ## comment out the above.
#    #proxy_pass http://phpapache;
}

## Run the update from the web interface with Drupal 7.
location = /authorize.php {
    fastcgi_pass phpcgi;
    ## To use Apache for serving PHP uncomment the line bellow and
    ## comment out the above.
    #proxy_pass http://phpapache;
}

location = /update.php {
    #auth_basic "Restricted Access"; # auth realm
    #auth_basic_user_file .htpasswd-users; # htpasswd file
    fastcgi_pass phpcgi;
    ## To use Apache for serving PHP uncomment the line bellow and
    ## comment out the above.
    #proxy_pass http://phpapache;
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful to see your Nginx configuration.

Comment: It is large and in multiple files. I followed a framework created for Drupal to supposedly cover all cases with some customization. Trying to keep the question simple. Added some details above.

Comment: Are you sure this is an nginx issue and not some type of PHP timeout? What kind of error do you receive?

Comment: No, not sure it is Nginx but I did this update on a test box first using Apache, then ran into this on the production box. I can find no errors on the log page or in MySQL or Nginx logs. The spinning indicator doesn't go for very long so it doesn't look like a timeout. It looks as if the script to update the db just doesn't get fired, the page never changes into the query display page, it stays unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

Look on this project https://github.com/perusio/drupal-with-nginx

You'll find nginx for drupal configuration there.